# How do I change the position in the video in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need a way to change the video position programmatically without scrubbing or using the default scrubber. However, the position value is not a setter so how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried doing controller.value.position = controller.value.duration but that won't work and I can't think of any other way to change the position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `VideoPlayerController` from the [video_player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player#-readme-tab-) package you can seek to the position you want programmatically by using the `seekTo()` method.

`controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds: /*any second you want*/ ));`

Comment: Thanks. Also would you be able to help me with another problem that I have. Whenever I press the back arrow and go back to my video later, the audio always starts from the place it left off earlier. I have tried troubleshooting this issue, but nothing I've done has worked.

Comment: @Coder : save its value. then seek.

Answer (score 5):

To start video where you left off earlier try below code:

```
controller..initialize().then((_){         
   setState(() {    
     controller.play();    
     controller.seekTo(controller.value.position + lastduration);
   });
});
```

It works for me

Comment: this should be a answer, personally. thanks

Comment: Why are we using setState here? Is calling an event on an initialised controller not enough to start playing without needing a rerender?

Comment: Try without setState and check if it working for you as state is not managed on page for seekTo I have used setState